# Unity build 3D models not showing on a different computer

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have an issue with my Unity build. I have some models, that on one computer that I have are correctly displayed.

However, I sent the build through Google Drive to another PC on which I need to run this build, and it does not work. In particular, those models that on the first PC are displayed are not shown.

What could cause this issue? I am using URP and Unity version 2021.3.5f1.

Comment: Is the aspect ratio the same? Like, are they cut off maybe?

Comment: Is not a problem of the aspect ratio, as they are moving models in front of the player, that come towards the player

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem: it was because the generation of these models were controlled by some `float` values taken from a file.

The `float` values were written as `0.01` (as an example). However, while one PC was in English, the other was in Italian, needing `0,01` as a `float` format. Changing the value it worked.